# Accessing fields in model in post procedure in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a post(self) and I want to add some logic here to add lat and lng (these are computed from google maps) to the data store as defined in my db model. Should I add to data, or should I do it some other way such as with the original class. What is the best way to do this?

so...

```
class Company(db.Model):
  company_type = db.StringProperty(required=True, choices=["PLC", "LTD", "LLC", "Sole Trader", "Other"])
  company_lat = db.StringProperty(required=True)
  company_lng = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class CompanyForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
  company_description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':'2', 'cols':'20'}))
  company_address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':'2', 'cols':'20'}))

  class Meta:
    model = Company
    exclude = ['company_lat,company_lng']


def post(self):
  data = CompanyForm(data=self.request.POST)
  map_url = ''  
  address = self.request.get("company_postcode")
  ...
  lat = response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
  lng = response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
  ...
  # How do I add these fields lat and lng to my data store?
  # Should I add them to data? if this is possible?
  # Or shall I do it some other way?
```

Thanks

Comment: @DrewSears Since I don't have edit rights, I cannot edit question to move `Meta` class inside `CompanyForm` class as it should be according to [Google App Engine djangoforms help page](http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/appengine/articles/djangoforms.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [djangoforms help page](http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/appengine/articles/djangoforms.html) explains how to add data to your datastore entity. Call `save` method with `commit=False`. It returns datastore entity and then you can add fields before saving it with `put()`

```
def post(self):
  ...
  # This code is after the code above
  if data.is_valid():
    entity=data.save(commit=False)
    entity.company_lat=lat
    entity.company_lng=lng
    entity.put()
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the types of queries you intend to do. If you want to perform geospatial queries, [GeoModel](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/geospatial.html) is built for your use case.